# how to open application while receive call?

Tags: xamarin, broadcastreceiver

In xamarin android application I have receive call using BroadcastReceiver

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        { 
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Received intent!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            DialerCallListener listener = new DialerCallListener(); 
            SIPRegistration.call = SIPRegistration.sipManager.TakeAudioCall(intent, listener);

            string str =  SIPRegistration.call.PeerProfile.UriString;

        }
```

From here I want to check my app is run in foreground/Background, and if it is background how can I bring my app to foreground and show incoming call receiving page? any help? it xamarin cross platform application.